# Looking for bolt with press nut

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm looking for a bolt without a thread that I can attach to an object using a kind of press nut. Whats the name of these kind of bolts and nuts? Can't find any information about it?

[image: Bolt with press nut]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The washer is often called a lock washer, star lock washer or clamping washer or ring.

The threadless bolt is often called a pin.

Answer (score 2):

One name it goes by is a PEM pin.

In addition to the various washer names given by Solar Mike, it might also be called various forms of push-on retaining clips/rings (whereas a normal retaining clip expects a groove).